# Android - Customizing the title bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-titlebar

I want to customize the title bar for an Android application. I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp" <!-- Problem here -->
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:background="@drawable/windowtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I also have a the following code in the targeted activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
        ... 
}
```

I don't understand why the height of the title bar doesn't change when changing the `android:layout_height` value.

Did I miss something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/), you should create a custom style for this. See if it works for you.

Comment: Actually, I have read it and I applied what's in there... Although I don't understand why we need to provide a custom style given we have the `window_title` layout. What does the custom_style add to the equation?

Answer (score 0):

set the layout_height as wrap_content or fill_parent of the linear layout

and then try it

Comment: I want to set a custom height. Also when providing an image background, the image is streched to fill up the width so the proportions are not the same as the original one.

Answer (score -1):

you can use :

```
getWindow().setLayout(50, 50);
```

of course this code use to set width and hiegth of window